# filter output with a loop: if {entry_id} not in array

Tags: channel-entries, ifelse

Within a loop, I need to output different info according to whether an entry is in an array of id's or not.

I currently get the id's from a query on the matrix table.

So I need something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="article"}

{if entry_id not in (ids)}
    //some output
{if: else}
    //some other output
{/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I can't use stash, and I can't figure how to do this with PHP/embedded templates/query tag, I think the parse order is a problem.

Here is the query I use to get the entries to filter on:

```
SELECT entry_id FROM exp_channel_titles
WHERE entry_id in 
(SELECT `child_entry_id` FROM (`exp_playa_relationships`)
WHERE `parent_field_id` =  '{embed:parent_field_id}'
ORDER BY `rel_order`)
```

Comment: Are we taking just a few key `entry_id`s? Or a few hundred out of a thousand? And what makes them special? There is almost certainly another identifier other than being in some random set of `entry_id`s.

Comment: Are you using [`group_concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)?

Comment: @jrothafer - there will be up to 200 entries in total, the filter will be 20 entries

Comment: After I improved my answer, I saw your update. You're using Playa, not Matrix. You're doing something really complex. Why not to use [`{exp:playa:child_ids}`](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/module/child_ids.html) on parent template?

Comment: sorry, it's playa in a matrix field!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using version 2.9+? Which is the separator?

Let's pretend you're and the separator is `,`, giving you something like `1,2,3,4,5`. Let's use the [contains](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/conditionals.html#contains-operator) and the [concatenation operators](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/conditionals.html#string-concatenation-operator).

### Using [Query Module](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/query/index.html)

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(entry_id SEPARATOR ',') AS array_of_ids FROM exp_matrix_data WHERE [...]" parse="inward"}

    {exp:channel:entries channel="article"}

    {if ",".array_of_ids."," *= ",".entry_id.","}
        //some output
    {if: else}
        //some other output
    {/if}

    {/exp:channel:entries}

{/exp:query}
```

### Using [`{exp:playa:child_ids}`](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/module/child_ids.html)

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="article"}

{if ","."{exp:playa:child_ids entry_id='{embed:parent_field_id}' field_id='XXXX' delimiter=','}"."," *= ",".entry_id.","}
    //some output
{if: else}
    //some other output
{/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is almost there, how do I get the array of ids, I don't think an embed will work?

Comment: @wot Like my first comment, what is the criteria that creates this group of `entry_id`s to be filtered? I guarantee there is a better way, like using categories to tag entries you want to skip.

Comment: The group of ids is fetched from a matrix field in another channel

Comment: You can write a custom query. But @jrothafer is right. Maybe there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is separate these specific entries and output them differently, use categories. You can then have content editors easily select (from the entry_form) entries that should be treated as such. You could have just a single category for this channel. Say it had `category_id` 10:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="article"}

    {categories}

        {if category_id == "10"}
            // Special output, in our special group
        {if:else}
            // Regular output, not so special
        {/if}

    {/categories}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

**Edit**

Ok, you get this info from a matrix field. How do you fetch it? Is it via a `{exp:query}` tag, or do you get it from another `{exp:channel:entries}` loop? I possibly smell a terrible PHP answer coming your way. Please continue to expand on your question with details.

Comment: I can't add categories to the entries, they are from a matrix field in another channel, so I'd still have to fetch the entries and loop through them.

Comment: I don't yet have a way to get the entries, this is part 2 of my problem, I have the sql but how do I use the results?

Comment: Please, @wot! Add the query you're using to your question, so I can help you. We can't write a query without to know why.